# Way to query database with SQLAlchemy where a date is a particular day of the week?

Tags: python, datetime, sqlalchemy

I have a table (called 'entry') which has a datetime column (called 'access_date'), and I want to do an SQLAlchemy query that only produces results where entry.access_date is a Monday (or any other day of the week specified by a number [0..6]).

Is this possible? I am using sqlite & SQLalchemy 0.5.8 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no generic DAYOFWEEK() function supported by SQLAlchemy, so you will have to use dialect-specific sql in the where clause.

For MySQL, you would go with custom func 'weekday' or 'dayofweek', but since sqlite has neither datetime type nor weekday()/dayofweek(), you need some raw sql there.

http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg51116.html here are examples for this query.

In SQLA, this will look like

```
query.filter("strftime('%w', access_date) = :dow").params(dow=0).all()
```

Comment: If I do:

for weekday in range(0,7):
    q = session.query(Entry).filter("strftime('%w',':date') = :dow").params(date=Entry.access_date, dow=weekday).all()


I get the error:

ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied

Comment: Oh, sorry, obviously we don't substitute it with actual date here, so it should be just `filter("strftime('%w', access_date) = :dow").params(dow=1)`

Comment: This question is pretty old, so I think that there is a new way of doing this now. After beating my head with this myself for awhile I found that  func.weekday(entry.access_date) actually exist in SQLAlchemy and works. :)

Answer (score 3):

Further from Daniel Kluev's answer, I found another way of saying the same thing (possibly nicer looking?)

```
query.filter(func.strftime('%w', Entry.access_date) == str(weekday)).all()
```

Where weekday is a number [0..6]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on SQLAlchemy, so await others' views. I've adapted an example from http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/ormtutorial.html#common-filter-operators. This may be worth testing & experimenting with while you wait for others' answers.:

```
query.filter(entry.access_date.in_([0,1,2,3,4,5,6]))
```

Comment: As I understand, his access_date column has DateTime type, so this will not work.

Comment: Yes, I tried query.filter(entry.access_date.weekday().in_([0,1,2,3,4,5,6]))
but as expected got an error:
 AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'weekday'